# Is there a way to avoid adding a reference to Entity Framework to my UI project without using a web service as a go-between?

Tags: .net, entity-framework, orm, entity-framework-core, ado.net

I'm trying to figure out a way for my UI class library, whether it be Win Forms, WPF, ASP.NET MVC etc., to not have any knowledge of Entity Framework or a connection string in its configuration file.  Basically, I want my UI project to not be concerned with what Data Access technology my Data Access project is using.  I don't want it to worry about if it is using LINQ, Entity Framework, basic ADO.NET or whatever.

The only way I know to accomplish this so far is to use a web service and have my UI project consume the service.  Overall, I really like Entity Framework, especially the way the Code-First option gives me much more stripped-down Entities than LINQ does, except I am struggling with this particular hurdle.

Comment: The first question is "why is it a hurdle?"   I don't recommend abstracting away EF simply for the purpose of abstracting it. EF gives you a LOT of power when dealing with data and abstracting it away either leads to overly complex code, poor performing code, or both. The worst thing you can do is try and abstract away it's implementation "just in case"  you decide later you *might* change to something else. Trust me, you almost certainly won't, and taking steps to try to will most likely result in issues leading to you considering that you need to.

Comment: My UI project should not be concerned with which data access technology the data access layer used.  The UI project should know nothing about databases, OEMs, or database connection strings.  My hurdle is my attempt to prevent this unnecessary and constrictive coupling.

Comment: EF Core itself does not require any configuration files. All it needs is populated `DbContextOptions`. Where and how you populate it is your business, not their concern. If you want it to be in data access layer - fine, just find a way how to provide that info for the data access layer. You can use whatever you find appropriate, but in any case there must be some sort of the externally configurable storage in case you don't hard code connection string and the database type.

Comment: If your UI *will* need to talk to various data sources (be it your own or third party, database or distributed service/brokerage, etc) then you need to define a common interface to represent the actions taken with data, and DTO definitions for the data the UI will need. My point is that *unless* this abstraction is a hard requirement of your UI, implementing such an abstraction in an application is a huge cost in complexity and ultimately in performance for nothing more than self-gratification or "just in case". Listen close for the warning sounds of YAGNI.

Comment: Your UI will request data from your UI layer.  It will not pass in connection strings or be concerned with where the data is stored or how the data is retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you create an interface for a service layer (library project) and use Dependency Injection to inject that service.
ASP.NET Core has Dependency Injection built in, so I will use that as an example. For your other UI projects it is the same concept. The only hurdle would be learning how to add Dependency Injection to those UI layers if they do not provide it.

I will use ASP.NET Core because it includes dependency injection out of the box and it is one you mentioned. You simply create a service layer as you said, and give it an Interface so it can be injected. You will inject the service layer using this Interface into your other UI projects as well.

If you are starting with a new project, this is usually not too much work. If you are adding it to an existing project, it could take an enormous amount of refactoring to achieve the required architecture. Be sure to do the refactoring in well thought out steps, because you might find a lot of design flaws along the way which must be changed in order to create this sort of abstraction if your UI layers are already depending directly on the data access layer.

First you must choose where you will store you connection strings, API keys and other configuration requirements.
One option is to use User Secrets. See for help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=windows
You can find other options as well and learn their implementations. Azure Key Vault for example.

You will need these layers for this example (Projects):

- UI Layer
- Business Layer (You may have one or more of these so it is good to have a
  Contracts layers as well)
- Contracts Layer (So that various UI layers can use it, and various business layers)
- Data Access Layer (DbContext using Entity Framework Core, could be any data access technology you choose)

The UI layer will call the Business layer and use DTOs from the Contracts Layer to pass data back and forth. The Business Layer needs to convert the DTO to an object or entity which the Data Access Layer uses. This keeps the layers decoupled.

Then you must inject the Business library into your UI project. The key in ASP.NET Core is to register an instance of your library's configuration options in Starup.cs so that, when the library is injected into the UI project, the library itself can be injected with an object which provides it with the information it needs to pass down to the Data Access Layer, such as connection strings. You can also use this object to configure your Business Layer if it ever needs some settings. Such as passing an APIKey to another service layer.

The IConfiguration instance in Startup.cs will load Providers (This is a property on the Configuration object, create a breakpoint and you can see what it loads), and one of those Providers will be the JSON in your User Secrets. It also has a method called GetSection which returns an instance of IOptions from Microsoft.Extensions.Options which you can use to create an instance of the configuration options your library needs to configure itself or pass down to other layers. In this example, I will be passing a connection string to the Data Access Layer.

To create this instance of your BusinessSerivceOptions, you must register it so that DI knows about it. You do this by reading it from User Secrets. This is done by using the Confiure method on the services collection in Startup.cs. The Confirure method takes a paramater of TOptions from Microsoft.Extensions.Options which you can get by calling Configuration.GetSection("name-of-section-in-user-secrets-json").

**In the UI Project:**

```
namespace SomeAspNetCoreUILayer
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            _configuration = configuration;
        }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddOptions;
            services.AddTransient<IBusinessServiceFactory, BusinessServiceFactory>()
            services.Configure<BusinessServiceOptions>(_configuration.GetSection(nameof(BusinessServiceOptions)));
            // ... The rest of your ConfigureServices code.
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env) 
        {
            // ... Your Configure code.
        }
    }
}
```

This would be the result. Of course your should use ViewModels not DTOs here, but I won't go into that:

```
namespace SomeAspNetCoreUiLayer.Controllers
{
    public class PersonController : Controller
    {
        private readonly BusinessServiceFactory _businessServices;
        public PersonController(IBusinessServiceFactory businessServiceFactory)
        {
            _businessServices = businessServiceFactory;
        }
        public IActionResult GetPerson(string personId)
        {
            PersonDTO = _businessService.SomeService.GetPerson(personId);
            return View(PersonDTO);
        }
    }
}
```

The library must have a class which models the structure in the User Secrets section you are telling GetSection to find, so that it can be serialized into that object when it is registered by services.Configure().

***In your User Secrets:***

```
{
    "BusinessServiceOptions": {
        "ConnectionStrings": {
            "MyDatabaseConnectionStringName": "...your connections string"
        },
        "ApiKeys": {
            "MyApiKey": "...your Api Key",
            "MyApiOtherKey": "...your other Api Key"
        }
}
```

***In the Business Library Project:***

```
namespace MyBusinessLibrary.Options
{
    public class BusinessServiceOptions
    {
        public ServiceConnectionStrings ConnectionStrings { get; set; }
        public ServiceApiKeys ApiKeys { get; set; }
        public class ServiceConnectionStrings
        {
            public string MyDatabaseConnectionStringName { get; set; }
        }
        public class ServiceApiKeys
        {
            public string MyApiKey { get; set; }
            public string MyOtherApiKey { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

```
namespace MyBusinessLibrary.Interface
{
    public interface IBusinessServiceFactory
    {
        BusinessServiceOptions Options { get; }
        SomeBusinessService SomeBusinessService { get; }
        SomeBusinessOtherService SomeBusinessOtherService { get; }
    }
    public class BusinessServiceFactory : IBusinessServiceFactory
    {
        private readonly BusinessServiceOptions _options;
        // This is so that the Configure<T>() can register the service in Startup.cs
        public BusinessServiceFactory(IOptions<BusinessServiceOptions> options)
        { 
            _options = options.Value;
        }
        // This will allow you to pass this BusinessServiceFactory instance to 
        // the service itself so it has access to the factory to call other
        // services if it needs them. (Without needing to implement IOptions in the services).
        public BusinessServiceFactory(BusinessServiceOptions options)
        {
            _options = options;
        }
        BusinessServiceOptions Options => _options;
        public SomeBusinessService SomeBusinessService => new SomeBusinessService(_options);
        public SomeBusinessOtherService SomeBusinessOtherService => new SomeBusinessOtherService(this);
    }
}
```

```
namespace MyBusinessLibrary.Services
{
    // Consider creating a BusinessServiceBase class and passing the passing options to the
    // base() instead, so that you don't have to write this code in every service that needs
    // access to the DbContext.
    public class SomeBusinessService
    {
        private readonly SomeDatabaseDbContext _SomeDatabase;
        public SomeBusinessService(BusinessServiceOptions options)
        {
            var SomeDatabaseDbContextOptionsBuilder = SqlServerDbContextOptionsExtensions.UseSqlServer(
            new DbContextOptionsBuilder<SomeDatabaseDbContext>(),
            options.ConnectionStrings.MyDatabaseConnectionStringName,
            sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout((int)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1).TotalSeconds));
            _SomeDatabase = new SomeDatabaseDbContext(SomeDatabaseDbContextOptionsBuilder.Options);
        }
        private PersonDTO GetPerson(string personId)
        {
            // Person will be the an Entity Framework Core class.
            Person person = _SomeDatabase.Person.Where(x => x.Id = personId).FirstOrDefault();
            // PersonDTO will be from your Contracts project so that the UI layer doesn't depend on the database layer classes.
            PersonDTO = new PersonDTO() { Id = person.Id, Name = person.Name }
            return PersonDTO;
        }
    }
}
```

***In the Database Library Project:***

```
namespace MyDatabaseLayer.DAL.Models
{
    public partial class SomeDatabaseDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public SomeDatabaseDbContext(DbContextOptions<SomeDatabaseDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public virtual DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
        // .. The rest of your DbContext code.
    }
    public partial class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***In the Contracts Library Project:***

```
namespace MyContractsProject.DataTransferObjects
{
    public class PersonDTO
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

***Addressing your concern about passing the connection string through the UI startup code in this answer:***

I feel like this answer addresses all original points in your question.

- Avoiding adding a reference to Entity Framework in your UI Project
- Removes knowledge of connections string in ***UI configuration files*** by taking them out and using an external secret storage
- Removes concern about data access technology knowledge used by the DAL from the UI
- Does not depend on requesting a connection string from a Web Service or any other external service for that matter.

The question shouldn't be "Can we avoid passing the connection string through the UI via Dependency Injection of the configuration options of a service layer." The answer is yes. The real question should be, "When should we, and, when we should, how should we do it? And when we shouldn't, what are our alternatives?"

Let's think more about the process. I think you would agree that a UI should be able to configure a library it uses. Understandably, you don't like that it passes the connection string.

However, let's take the side of the library for a moment and consider your request to not use a Web Service. There are three options. The library is passed, requests, or contains the string.

You never want to hard code, so containing is out.

A library should not be dependent on who is calling it and it should not know about its locational relationship to a connection string. If that is a requirement, then the library's consumers must know this and be built in such a way. Basically, the consumer must have knowledge of the library's logic for acquiring it's dependencies. Because this couples the UI and the library, the library shouldn't predict the connection string location.

The library should be passed the string or directions for how to find the string via configuration options. In your question, you said you don't want to use an external service. But let's say you did. Even if the library uses an external service to request that information, the library will need to tell that external service which string to look for so it can return it. How will the library know what string to ask for if information identifying the string is not hard coded or passed into it so it can ask the service? A library requires an application to instantiate its objects. If you don't want a UI or one of its dependent libraries to pass it in, you have no more appropriate options.

The only things I can think of is to design an app which all UI and libraries depend on to run which starts them up, and that dependency would couple everything together which defeats the purpose of decoupling your application layers. Now your UI or some of it's libraries will not work independent of "The One App to Rule Them All."

It appears you may believe the design patters you are learning are hard rules. Being a Software Engineer is a practical art as much as it is a hard science. The important thing we need to focus on as developers and engineers is to understand the patterns and to achieve an appropriate design based on a practical need.

Comment: I appreciate the detailed and informative response. However, I have a concern regarding the following statement.

"the library itself can be injected with an object which provides it with the information it needs to pass down to the Data Access Layer, such as connection strings."

From my viewpoint, the UI layer should only request data from the Data Access layer, not provide connection strings or the how to details of any data access tasks. Your UI layer should not know what a connection string is any more than the Data Access layer should know what a TextBox is.

Comment: Specifically, I don't like the way the UI is not being allowed to not be concerned with the fact that the Data Access Library is using Entity Framework.  It is one thing to say it can pass dependencies in.  It is another entirely to say that the UI layer needs a dependency to the data access technology.

Comment: Look deeper at my answer, the UI has absolutely no clue what data technology is being implemented in the DAL.

Comment: Please look at the EDIT on bottom of my answer. I added it to address your concern regarding registering the library configuration object with information before the library is registered into the dependency injection implementation.

Comment: I believe I answered your original question accurately and that it will help anyone who is trying to answer that specific question. It appears that my answer has lead to the true topic you want to explore. If you agree that the question has changed, you might want to mark this as answered if you feel I answered the original question, it might help others, and open a new thread where you can reword your question and we can discuss any further details you may still have. It just seems like we are delving into a different topic now. This is no longer about the EF dependency in the UI.